# javascript document.getElement.setAttribute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, document, getelementbyid, setattribute

I have this problem:

On this website: http://www.azercell.com/WebModule1/mainservlet?cmnd=sms&lang=en

I'm trying the following script, it works fine with C#, but javascript nope, why?

```
javascript:(function() { 
    document.getElementById('login').setAttribute('value', 'test'); })()
```

Comment: Where and when do you want to do this? Onclick of something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
javascript:(function() { 
   document.getElementById('login').value="test";
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this answer is completely incorrect... also, please stop reading w3schools as per http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Sorry but please explain at least why this answer is incorrect... I just wrote down what i found in that piece of documentation... What are you basing your comment on?

Comment: DOM elements in JavaScript do have a `setAttribute()` method, but your suggestion of using the `value` property is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main problems.

1. The script doesn't appear in the page.
2. While there is an element with `name="value"`, there is no element with `id="value"`. (So `getElementById('value')` won't return an element except in IE 7 and earlier (which is buggy) and rendering modes that try to be compatible with those bugs)

Give the element you want to target a suitable id attribute.